# Unable to start Docker example w/apache-php

Tags: docker

I am following a [tutorial](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-customize-docker-images-with-dockerfiles) about Docker. I run on Windows, so I already installed Docker for Windows and signed up for the Hub.

Currently I am in the process of creating my very first Apache instance on Docker.

Following the tutorial, I created the very first Dockerfile of a `debian` derivative and ran the container. My output was consistent with the tutorial (`>` denotes Windows prompt)

```
> docker run -it --name mydebian_container  mydebian
root@ef9eb174874a:/# ps -ef
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root         1     0  0 02:43 pts/0    00:00:00 bash
root         9     1  0 02:43 pts/0    00:00:00 ps -ef
```

Then I followed the tutorial on running Apache from the container

Dockerfile

```
FROM debian
RUN apt-get update &&\
    apt-get -y install procps libapache2-mod-php
CMD service apache2 start
```

Cool, yea? But when I run the container nothing happens, and the container itself exits successfully

```
D:\IdeaDevOps\dockers\apache2>docker run -it --name apache2  -v d:\IdeaDevOps\dockers\apache2:/var/www/html  debian_apache2
[....] Starting Apache httpd web server: apache2AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.17.0.2. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
. ok


>docker ps --all
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS               NAMES
09d5b4b3fa49        debian_apache2      "/bin/sh -c 'service…"   24 seconds ago      Exited (0) 22 seconds ago                       apache2
8d1c4522aa30        mydebian            "bash"                   2 hours ago         Exited (0) 2 hours ago                          elated_wing
ae769d388b36        ubuntu              "bash"                   2 hours ago         Exited (0) 2 hours ago                          kind_murdock
5596841696f6        mydebian            "bash"                   2 hours ago         Exited (0) 2 hours ago                          festive_booth
```

I really can't figure why it fails to keep a running Apache server. `AH00558` is a **warning**, it never blocks Apache from starting up.
I have a running instance of Apache 2.4 on my laptop listening on 80, so I stopped the Windows service relative to it.

I also tried to change the port bindings in Docker, or to not pass any port binding (`-p`) to Docker to see what happens.

As you can see, I am not running the container `-d` on purpose (unlike the linked tutorial) to see its output.

What is preventing the Apache-based container to start? I am not really interested in running a real Apache/php, but I just want to get acquainted with Docker and how to customize an image for your needs. TL;DR I am learning, do not have a real business need now.

### Update

I tried to use a hammer of Thor approach. If I insisted in doing `docker start apache2` I can get the Apache server alive for a few seconds only, just the time to browse the root directory on my browser. The server ends eventually

```
D:\IdeaDevOps\dockers\apache2>docker start apache2
apache2

D:\IdeaDevOps\dockers\apache2>docker start apache2
apache2

D:\IdeaDevOps\dockers\apache2>docker start apache2
apache2

D:\IdeaDevOps\dockers\apache2>docker start apache2
apache2

D:\IdeaDevOps\dockers\apache2>docker start apache2
apache2

D:\IdeaDevOps\dockers\apache2>docker start apache2
apache2

D:\IdeaDevOps\dockers\apache2>docker exec apache2 bash

D:\IdeaDevOps\dockers\apache2>docker exec apache2 bash

D:\IdeaDevOps\dockers\apache2>docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                NAMES
c669aacbed7a        debian_apache2      "/bin/sh -c 'service…"   20 minutes ago      Up 17 seconds       0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp   apache2

D:\IdeaDevOps\dockers\apache2>docker ps --all
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                    PORTS               NAMES
c669aacbed7a        debian_apache2      "/bin/sh -c 'service…"   20 minutes ago      Exited (1) 1 second ago                       apache2
8d1c4522aa30        mydebian            "bash"                   2 hours ago         Exited (0) 2 hours ago                        elated_wing
ae769d388b36        ubuntu              "bash"                   2 hours ago         Exited (0) 2 hours ago                        kind_murdock
5596841696f6        mydebian            "bash"                   2 hours ago         Exited (0) 2 hours ago                        festive_booth

D:\IdeaDevOps\dockers\apache2>docker ps --all
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS               NAMES
c669aacbed7a        debian_apache2      "/bin/sh -c 'service…"   21 minutes ago      Exited (1) 23 seconds ago                       apache2
8d1c4522aa30        mydebian            "bash"                   2 hours ago         Exited (0) 2 hours ago                          elated_wing
ae769d388b36        ubuntu              "bash"                   2 hours ago         Exited (0) 2 hours ago                          kind_murdock
5596841696f6        mydebian            "bash"                   2 hours ago         Exited (0) 2 hours ago                          festive_booth
```

Comment: Is it to say that **the tutorial** is broken?

Comment: This tutorial guides you to use `service start` but this is something one would use in VMs. Containers are not VMs. More here: [systemd and systemctl within Ubuntu Docker images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39169403/systemd-and-systemctl-within-ubuntu-docker-images). Check the answer provided by [BMitch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/596285/bmitch)

Comment: @usr-local-ΕΨΗΕΛΩΝ Possibly yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A docker container needs a hold on a process to stay up.

When you run "service apache2 start", the service is started, and that's it, the container stops.

So you should use a command that keeps running, like : `apachectl -D FOREGROUND`

Comment: What's the point of voting for closing as duplicate and then provide an answer?

Comment: @leopal as you said : it's a vote. Maybe it's not a duplicate, and in this case I have an answer...

Comment: I answered to help questioner quickly identify a solution and then I would vote for closing as dup, but you did it for me. Anyway, I believe it is indeed a duplicate.